# Fixed element inside absolute element z-index does not work

Tags: html, css, css-position

I got two `absolute` elements with the same `z-index`.
One of them has a `fixed-position` child which has an higher `z-index` than the parent.

Why the child only overlaps the parent but not the other absolute element with a lower `z-index`. 
How to achieve that the child overlaps both lower `z-index` elements?

```css
.lower-element {
  background: green;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.higher-element {
  background: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 20;
}

.lower-element-1 {
  top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="lower-element">
  <div class="higher-element">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lower-element lower-element-1">
</div>
```

Comment: Is your html code editable?

Comment: It depends on the changes.

Comment: Can we put your higher-element as siblings of lower-element?

Comment: Yes maybe. Seems to be the only working solution since there is [no other possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459779/fixed-element-inside-absolute-element-z-index-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment95728219_54459875).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making `.higher-element` to be siblings with `.lower-element`, then set `.higher-element` with `z-index: -1`

```css
.lower-element {
  background: green;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.higher-element {
  background: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: -1;
}

.lower-element-1 {
  top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="lower-element"> 
</div>
<div class="higher-element">
</div>
<div class="lower-element lower-element-1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`position: fixed` and `position: absolute` only usable with the​ `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `right` values.

```css
.lower-element {
  background: green;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.higher-element {
  background: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 20;
  top:5em; /* I added */
}

.lower-element-1 {
  top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="lower-element">
  <div class="higher-element">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lower-element lower-element-1">
</div>
```

Comment: In this approach the child (higher-element) still not overlapping both lower-elements?

Comment: Child's cannot dominate their parents.

Comment: In my example they can or am I wrong? The `higher-element` overlappes the parent. But elements outside this hierarchy (`lower-element-1`) are the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all your `z-index` and add only to `.higher-element` : `z-index: -1;`

```css
.lower-element {
  background: green;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  position: absolute;
}

.higher-element {
  background: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: -1;
}

.lower-element-1 {
  top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="lower-element">
  <div class="higher-element">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lower-element lower-element-1">
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: This solution works. But in my production case I need that z-index on that lower-elements.. :(

Comment: so use `z-index:10` to `lower-elements`

Comment: This is not working for some reason. Setting `higher-element { z-index: -1 }` and `lower-element { z-index: 10 }`.

Comment: @tomole setting z-index to lower element will simply make this impossible as you will create a stacking context